# How to use .wic files with qemu

Tags: qemu, sd-card, wic

I am trying to use `qemu` with the machine `microchip-icicle-kit`, following the instructions from https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/riscv/microchip-icicle-kit.html (even though it seems a bit outdated, since the step with `$ wget ftp://ftpsoc.microsemi.com/outgoing/core-image-minimal-dev-icicle-kit-es-sd-20201009141623.rootfs.wic.gz` doesn't work because that file is not found, but i found the .wic file from [here](https://github.com/polarfire-soc/meta-polarfire-soc-yocto-bsp/releases/tag/v2022.09#:%7E:text=SMP%3A%20core%2Dimage%2Dminimal%2Ddev%2Dicicle%2Dkit%2Des))

After following the last step: `$ minicom -D unix\#serial1.sock` in another terminal, nothing happens and both terminals seem stuck (Only `CTRL + C` stops them).

In the first terminal window (where `qemu` was executed) this is printed: `info: QEMU waiting for connection on: disconnected:unix:serial1.sock,server=on`

And in the second terminal:

"Welcome to minicom 2.7.1

OPTIONS: I18n
Compiled on Dec 23 2019, 02:06:26.
Port unix#serial1.sock

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys"

Is it really necessary to flash the .wic file to a physical sd-card? Perhaps that is the problem?